# SVN how to add ALL ? file.java to server?

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN , when I use this command :

`svn stat`

, I have a list of files like this : 
? file1.java
? file2.java
....
Now , I have to to add all of them to server using the command :

```
svn add file1.java
```

I wonder if there is a way to add all ? file.java with only 1 command? 
Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what OS your using to run the svn client.

Comment: Thanks! I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

if your shell supports recursive globbing (zsh) you can use something like

```
svn add **/file*.java
```

with other shells you might need to craft some `find`/`xargs`-based command.

alternatively you can use

```
svn add .
```

to add everything

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I tried and I had this :
svn: '**' is not a working copy
svn: '**' does not exist